# slow mysql query, set indexes or optimise

Tags: mysql

I have a queries like below.  Can these be optimized or can someone suggest a how to index?

```
SELECT  t1.`Geo ID`, 
        t1.`Sub Unit Geo ID`, 
        t1.`Sub Unit SW ID`, 
        t1.`Building No`, 
        t1.`Building Name`, 
        t1.Road, 
        t2.ID `Matching NEW_ID`, 
        t2.Sub, 
        t2.SUB_BUILDING_NAME, 
        t2.BUILDING_NAME,
        t2.BUILDING_NUMBER, 
        t2.THOROUGHFARE, 
        t2.E - t1.Easting `East Difference`, 
        t2.N - t1.Northing `North Difference` 
FROM    upcdata t1 JOIN 
        newer t2    ON  (t2.E * 1000) BETWEEN t1.Easting - 25000 AND t1.Easting + 25000 
                    AND (t2.N * 1000) BETWEEN t1.Northing - 25000 AND t1.Northing + 25000 
                    AND t1.Road = t2.THOROUGHFARE 
                    AND t1.`Building Name` = t2.BUILDING_NAME 
                    AND t1.`Building Name` <> ""
ORDER BY    t1.`Geo ID`
```

Comment: That's not what we're here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes aren't used for calculated values, but you can alter your query so solve that!
Change your `between` to put the multiplication on the values:

```
....
join newer t2
    ON t2.E BETWEEN (t1.Easting - 25000)/1000 AND (t1.Easting + 25000)/1000
    AND t2.N BETWEEN (t1.Northing - 25000)/1000 AND (t1.Northing + 25000)/1000
....
```

The comparison is mathematically identical, but it means the between has 2 fixed values to look up on, rather than having to multiply the t2 values for every row *and* not use an index because of it.

Even without indexes, just avoiding millions of computations will make it much faster